# alternative F# clarinet fingering

Tags: fingering, clarinet

On my Schreiber clarinet with Oehler key system (or german system) the alternative F# fingering (right side of the image) produces not a F# but a slightly flat G instead while the normal fingering (left side of the image) is working fine.

[image]
[image]
http://www.klarinette24.de/grifftabelle.html

Any explanations for this?

Comment: That's a cross-fingering, so it's going to be very sensitive to the amount the F-key-pad opens. As an experiment play that fingering and very slightly press the low F-key. If that brings the note down to pitch then you know the pad is opening too much and the cork needs to be adjusted.

Comment: Sure sounds (sorry) like you need to adjust a cork pad or a bent key somewhere.  If you're not experienced in clarinet maintenance, probably better to take it to a local repair shop

Comment: Thanks for your comments, it was indeed an adjustment of a cork pad which fixed the issue.